# MediaRecorder - проблема установки CamcorderProfile

Tags: android, видео, mediarecorder

При попытке снять качество видео в промежутке от 176x144 (QCIF) до 720x480(480P) ну, например: QVGA (320 x 240) или CIF(352 x 288) путём установки CamcorderProfile - ничего не работает. И если на Андроиде 6 телефон снимает просто как заниженное QCIF, то на 4.4.4 - вообще все попытки в этом диапазоне крошат приложение. При установки же значений 2, 4, 5, 6 (что соответствует QCIF, 480P, 720P ...) в CamcorderProfile - камера записывает всё прекрасно и параметры видео выходят соответствующими). Кто нибудь уже наступал на эти грабли?